# JLabel Font to big

Tags: java, jlabel

I Have a JLabel with a custom font.

If i draw a Text with Graphics2D and also the same font it looks way smaller(as it should be) compared to the JLabel.

[image: Graphics2D and JLabel]

If I set a higher Font size for the JLabel (around 110px) the font behaves as it should be.

[image: JLabel with high fontsize]

I load the Font with:

```
 Font.createFont(TRUETYPE_FONT, new File(path));
 GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
 ge.registerFont(font);
```

And set it to the label with:

```
label.setFont(font);
```

Someone know the problem or a solution?

Comment: I don't think this has to do anything with the font size, but instead with the actual font being used.  It appears that when you are painting the correct font is being used, but when setting it directly the incorrect font is being used...unless you have some attributes set like bold.  Can you post your code for setting the text in both ways?

Comment: Yes, I had a similar presumption. Sysout gives the correct font, really strange. It's `g2D.drawString("Font-size: 60px", 50, 50);` and `label = new JLabel("Font-size: 60px", SwingConstants.CENTER);`

Comment: Don't know the problem. But it helps to register every font, also different font sizes, to the GraphicsEnvironment before uses.